# Invalid Object Name -- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Right now I am getting an error of 'Invalid object name qryTI_3'. I only get this error when I try to execute the entire procedure, but I can still save the procedure. I have verified that all the fields do exist in the table referenced. What is wrong with this query?

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


WITH qryTI_1 AS 
(
SELECT tblTSF.fldFPK, tblTSF.fldPK, tblTSF.fldCI, tblTSF.fldNI
FROM tblTSF
WHERE (((tblTSF.fldMN)<>-254))
),

qryTI_2 AS 
(
SELECT tblTSF.fldFPK, tblTSF.fldPK, tblAL.fldLN AS fldCI, 0 AS fldNI
FROM tblAL, tblTSF
GROUP BY tblTSF.fldFPK, tblTSF.fldPK, tblAllLevels.fldLN
HAVING (((tblAL.fldLN)<>0 And (tblAL.fldLN)<>6))
),

qryTI_3 AS 
(
SELECT * FROM qryTI_1 UNION SELECT * FROM qryTI_2
)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(fldCI) 
                    from qryTI_3
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT fldPK, fldFPK, ' + @cols + '
                FROM 

                (
                SELECT fldPK
                        ,fldFPK
                        ,fldNI
                        ,fldCI
                FROM qryTI_3    
                ) as x
                PIVOT
                (
                    Sum(fldNI) FOR fldCI IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) as p '

        execute sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CTE only exists for the duration of that statement.

```
   WITH
     cte1 AS
   (blah)
   ,
     cte2 AS
   (blah)
   ,
     cte3 AS
   (blah)

   statement1;  -- The CTE definitions are part of this statement 

   statement2;  -- They are not part of this statement, they're gone by now
```

So, once your `SET` statement completes, the CTE is gone too, before you ever reach the `execute` call.

Not to mention the fact that your call to `execute` has also created a new scope, within which the CTE and variables don't exist either.

Try making these views instead of CTEs - So that they exist for more than one statement, and are visible within the scope created by your call to `execute`.